# Given a buffer (void*) and an encoding name, how can I find a string or character's index?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, encoding

I have a `void*` to a buffer (and its length, in bytes). I also know the text encoding of the buffer, it might be plain ASCII, UTF-8, Shift-JIS, UTF-16 (both LE or BE), or something else. And I need to find out if "`<<<`" appears in the buffer.

I'm using C++11 (VS2013) and coming from a .NET background the problem wouldn't be that hard: create an `Encoding` object instance for the encoding, then pass it the data (as `Byte[]`) and convert it to a `String` instance (internally using UTF-16LE), and use the string functions `IndexOf` or a `Regex`.

However the C++ equivalent doesn't necessarily work as Microsoft's C++ runtime library, specifically its implementation of `locale`, does not support UTF-8 multi-byte encoding (a complete mystery to me). I'm also not keen on the prospect of performing so many buffer copies (like how in .NET, you would `Marshal.Copy` the `void*` into `Byte[]`, and then again into a `String` via the `Encoding` instance.

Here's the psuedo-code high-level logic I'm after:

```
const char* needle = "<<<";

size_t IndexOf(void* buffer, size_t bufferCB, std::string encodingName, std::string needle) {

    char* needleEncoded = Convert( needle, encodingName );

    setlocale( encodingName );
    size_t index = strstr( buffer, bufferCB, needleEncoded );
    return index;
}
```

My versions of `setlocale` and `strstr` aren't in the standard, but exemplify the kind of behaviour I need.

Comment: why EVER use void* in C++? Maybe try templates instead

Comment: @TheOne data is passed to my function by third-party software that passes a buffer as `void*`.

Comment: Use `ConvertINetString` to covert the string to an encoding of your choice. Use `IMultiLanguage::GetCharsetInfo` to convert encoding name into corresponding `CP_*` constant.

Comment: Alternatively, note that 7-bit ASCII characters tend to be represented as-is in most text encodings; the exception being UTF-16 and UTF-32. So, apart from these special cases, you could just search the original buffer for `<<<`; for UTF-16LE, search for `<\0<\0<\0`, and so on. Use `std::search` so that you don't need to care about embedded NULs.